# move in any step of nebular stepper

Tags: angular, nebular, nebula

I am working with `Nebular` in `angular 2`, I am using the `stepper` with four steps, how can I move with the buttons of the steps to any desired step ? without having previously selected the steps ?, for example from `step 1` to  `step 4` or from `step 1` to `step 3`, but it does not allow me to perform these actions.

[image]

For this example I will use the code from the documentation. [nbsteppercomponent](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/stepper/overview#nbsteppercomponent)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  template: `
    <nb-card>
      <nb-card-body>
        <nb-stepper orientation="horizontal" disableStepNavigation>
          <nb-step [label]="labelOne">
            <ng-template #labelOne>First step</ng-template>
            <h4>Step content #1</h4>
            <p class="lorem">
              Lorizzle ipsum dolizzle stuff fizzle, consectetuer adipiscing break it down.
              Nullizzle sapien velizzle, my shizz pimpin', shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle shut the shizzle up,
              gravida vizzle, dang.
            </p>
            <button class="prev-button" nbButton disabled nbStepperNext>prev</button>
            <button class="next-button" nbButton nbStepperNext>next</button>
          </nb-step>
          <nb-step [label]="labelTwo">
            <ng-template #labelTwo>Second step</ng-template>
            <h4>Step content #2</h4>
            <p class="lorem">
              Lorizzle ipsum dolizzle stuff fizzle, consectetuer adipiscing break it down.
              Nullizzle sapien velizzle, my shizz pimpin', shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle shut the shizzle up,
              gravida vizzle, dang.
            </p>
            <button class="prev-button" nbButton nbStepperPrevious>prev</button>
            <button class="next-button" nbButton nbStepperNext>next</button>
          </nb-step>
          <nb-step label="Third step">
            <h4>Step content #3</h4>
            <p class="lorem">
              Lorizzle ipsum dolizzle stuff fizzle, consectetuer adipiscing break it down.
              Nullizzle sapien velizzle, my shizz pimpin', shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle shut the shizzle up,
              gravida vizzle, dang.
            </p>
            <button class="prev-button" nbButton nbStepperPrevious>prev</button>
            <button class="next-button" nbButton nbStepperNext>next</button>
          </nb-step>
          <nb-step [label]="labelFour">
            <ng-template #labelFour>Fourth step</ng-template>
            <h4>Step content #4</h4>
            <p class="lorem">
              Lorizzle ipsum dolizzle stuff fizzle, consectetuer adipiscing break it down.
              Nullizzle sapien velizzle, my shizz pimpin', shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle shut the shizzle up,
              gravida vizzle, dang.
            </p>
            <button class="prev-button" nbButton nbStepperPrevious>prev</button>
            <button class="next-button" nbButton disabled nbStepperNext>next</button>
          </nb-step>
        </nb-stepper>
      </nb-card-body>
    </nb-card>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./stepper-disabled-step-nav.component.scss'],
})
export class StepperDisabledStepNavComponent {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable the linear mode adding this code:

```
<nb-stepper [linear]=false orientation="horizontal" disableStepNavigation>
```

then you can add a function inside your button to navigate wherever your want between your steps